# Should I report accounts that were just made to spam/promotion links?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I noticed today that a same link had been posted to two different questions from two different users.

- [Yolili](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/99994/yolili) - posted in the [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35778/how-do-you-restore-files-from-an-icloud-backup/155599#155599)
- [babalala](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/99995/babalala) - posted in the [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99276/having-trouble-restoring-backup-of-my-iphone/155600#155600)

Both those answers have search terms which the user is trying to promote for SEO. I've reported the questions, should I report the users as well?

This brings upon a bigger question where there are some users who've created accounts just for posting a answer with a link to a website like - [example user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/75960/user75960) who posted an answer for this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35778/how-do-you-restore-files-from-an-icloud-backup/127837#127837), which seems to be okay but the link is shortened which raises a flag for spam i think.

How should such user accounts be handled ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell: Flagging the answers as spam (or just for moderator attention) is absolutely ok in these cases.

We look into the account when we get notified of spam messages, so there is no urgent need to flag the user as well (especially if you already flagged the answer).